# Why is there no org.hibernate.hql.antlr package in Hibernate source code?

Tags: java, hibernate

I downloaded the source code of hibernate3.5 from GitHub, but org.hibernate.hql.antlr package is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tv5g.png)

Who can help me, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to copy the ANTLR parser of Hibernate 3.2 to version 3.5, including (grammar folder, lib folder, build. xml, and build. bat). Then the source code will copy the grammar file from the G file under core.src.main.antlr. Modify the build.xml configuration, find the antlrtask label, add the corresponding configuration, it is good. Although not much, it solved the problem.